# Copying only completed files in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, copy

I am trying to complete a task to copy all the files from a directory to another location.

This will be an ongoing script so I will be copying files every 5s and then deleting the files once they are copied.

The only catch is, I need to make sure that the file is complete before I copy it (i.e not being modified any longer)

Is there anyway to find out if the file is being used/is open?

Thank you for the help

Comment: As a bonus ```fuser``` is part of POSIX so you could make this run on OS/X, BSD, Linux, Solaris. HP-UX, AIX ... :-) 
Be star and be (POSIX-ly) cross platform!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`fuser`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) command. It will tell you the process(es) which have the file open.

Comment: perfect, I can use that and it's return code :) thank you so much!!

Comment: for some reason... this is not working. I am writing to a file constantly, and when i `fuser` it, I get a return value of 1 not 0.... any reasons why this would happen? `lsof` also gives me the same problem